# Ajax change php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got this variable `$type` and I want it to be `month` or `year`.
It should be changed by pressing a `div`.

I've tried creating an `onclick` event with an ajax call.

The `ajax` call and the `variable` are in the same script (`index.php`)

Inside the onclick function:

```
var curr_class = $(this).attr('class');


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: {
        type: curr_class
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        // Test what is returned from the server
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But the alert returns the *whole* html page.
When I console.log the data (create a `var data = { type:curr_class }) and console.log *that data* it returns`type = month` (which is correct)

while I just want it to return *month* or *year*

So on top of the page I can call

```
if(empty($_POST['type'])){
     $type = 'month';
} else {
     $type = $_POST['type'];
}
```

and change the PHP variable so I can use it in the rest of my script.

But how can I accomplish this?

With kind regards,

Comment: You should not make an ajax request to your `index.php` if you don't want the content of `index.php` returned. Instead, write a separate script to handle your ajax requests.

Comment: But how do I change the *PHP variable* then? @jeroen

Comment: There is no such thing as *the PHP variable*. Each variable only is set during the execution of the script, it does not exist after the script has finished (unless you use a session, database, etc. to store the information).

Comment: Thanks @jeroen I used session. It works now

Answer (score 0):

as you are sending request to the same page so as a result full page is return .You will have to send it to another page and from that page return the type variable

```
if(empty($_POST['type'])){
 $type = 'month';
 } else {
   $type = $_POST['type'];
   echo $type;
```

keep this code in separate file and make an ajax call to that page

Comment: Use only Jquery code not in php bcoz we can not get runtime variable  value in php

Comment: and how do I *use* that variable at a different part of the code?

Comment: save it in session varable

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This It's Work 
<a href="Javascript:void(0);" class="btn-my" data-title="month">Get Value</a>
<a href="Javascript:void(0);" class="btn-my" data-title="year">Get Value</a>
$(".btn-my").click(function(){
    var curr_class = $(this).data('title');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
            type: curr_class
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            // Test what is returned from the server
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Returns entire html page